# How to Set java ZonedDateTime value to Cassandra Timestamp field

Tags: cassandra, jhipster, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have generated Microservice jhpister API which uses cassandra as db. I have generated entities using yo jhipster: entity entityname. While generating fields I have given ZonedDateTime as datatype for field CreatedOn. So it created TimeStamp as datatype in cassandra table and in java entity with ZonedDateTime. I have some custom insert code using BindStatement

```
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(insertStatement.bind()
.setTimestamp("createdOn", existingWorkAssignment.getCreatedOn());
```

But this generates compile time error which says cannot resolve method becuase the value we are setting is zoneddatetime but the internal cassandra data type is timestamp. Please help

Answer (score 0):

first convert the ZonedDateTime value to Timestamp the set the value.

Try doing like this.
Example:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime =ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.now());
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

In Your case

```
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(insertStatement.bind()
  .setTimestamp("createdOn", Timestamp.valueof(existingWorkAssignment.getCreatedOn().toLocalDateTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Datastax suggests using tuple to store ZonedDateTime as Timestamp and ZoneInfo separately. The example can be found [there](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/extras/)